# Shortcode with foreach

Tags: shortcode

I can't use shortcode with foreach. It gives me syntax error. Where i am wrong?

```
function create_galeri_shortcode($atts) {

$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
    ),
    $atts,
    'galeri'
);

if ( has_post_format( 'gallery' )) {
    $images = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'vdw_gallery_id', true);
    if($images) {
        $out = '<div id="lightgallery">'.
        foreach ($images as $imageid) {
        $altyazi = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ).'
        <a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($imageid, 'large').'" data-sub-html=".caption">
            <img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url($imageid, 'thumbnail').'" alt="'.$altyazi.'">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>'.$altyazi.'</h4><p>'.wp_get_attachment_caption($imageid).'</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        '.}.'
        </div>';
    }
}
return $out;
}
add_shortcode( 'galeri_mm', 'create_galeri_shortcode' );
```

Comment: you cannot create a string like that. it's a PHP question and not WordPress related.

Comment: So i can't asq this question here right?

Comment: syntax errors are simple to fix, if you do not understand what they mean, you should ask about it, but again this is the wrong place for such questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate a `foreach` statement in to a string, which can't be done... You need to add the output that you need to your existing string, not concatenate it

```
function create_galeri_shortcode( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
        ),
        $atts,
        'galeri'
    );

    if ( has_post_format( 'gallery' ) ) {
        $images = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'vdw_gallery_id', true );
        if( $images ) {
            $out = '<div id="lightgallery">'.
            foreach ($images as $imageid) {
                $altyazi = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
                $out .= '<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($imageid, 'large').'" data-sub-html=".caption">';
                    $out .= '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url($imageid, 'thumbnail').'" alt="'.$altyazi.'">';
                    $out .= '<div class="caption">';
                        $out .= '<h4>'.$altyazi.'</h4>'; 
                        $out .= '<p>'.wp_get_attachment_caption( $imageid ).'</p>';
                    $out .= '</div>';
                $out .= '</a>';
            }
            $out .= '</div>';
        }
    }
return $out;
}
add_shortcode( 'galeri_mm', 'create_galeri_shortcode' );
```